# Parse only date from a line in text file

Tags: perl

I have a text file with delimiters as spaces at the start of the lines.

Lines with no initial spaces should go in the first column of the CSV file; those with two spaces should go in the second column of the CSV; and those with four spaces should go in the third column.

This is all working fine as required.

In lines starting with two spaces I want that only the date should go in the second column, discarding the other data of the line. The rest should all remain as it is.

I have denoted spaces at the start of the line as `#` for clarity.

Text file:

```
Component1
##(111) Amar Sen <amar.sen@gmail.com> <No comment> 2013/04/01
####/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt
##(1199) Prashant Singh <psinsgh@gmail.com> <No comment> 2013/04/24
####/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24
####/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile25
####/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile26
##(1204) Anthony Li <anthon.li@gmail.com> <No comment> 2013/04/25
####/Com/src2
Component2(added)
Component3
```

Output format:

```
Component1,2013/04/01,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt
           2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24
                  /Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile25
                      /Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile26
           2013/04/25,/Com/src2
Component2(added)
Component3
```

Here's the code. Its working fine except for the change described above.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $previous_count            = "-1"; #beginning, we will think, that no spaces.
my $current_count             = "0";  #current default value
my $maximum_count             = 3;
my $to_written                = "";
my $delimiter_between_columns = ",";
my $newline_separator         = ";";

my $file = 'C:\\textfile.txt';
open (my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file) or die "Could not open file '$file' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {

  # ok, read.
  chomp($row);

  # print "row is : $row\n";
  if ($row =~ m/^(\s*)/) {

    #print length($1);
    $current_count = length($1) / 2;    #take number of spaces divided by 2
    $row =~ s/^\s+//;

    if ($previous_count >= $current_count || $previous_count == $maximum_count) {

      #output here
      print "$to_written" . $newline_separator . "\n";

      $previous_count = 0;
      $to_written     = "";
    }
    $previous_count = 0 if ($previous_count == -1);
    $to_written .= $delimiter_between_columns x ($current_count - $previous_count) . "$row";

    $previous_count = $current_count;

    #print"\n";
  }
}

print "$to_written" . $newline_separator . "\n";
```

Comment: The "output format" you posted doesn't match what you described you want, where you have`. Since CSV fields are delimited by commas, any line with no comma means that all the content is in the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have got yourself tied up in knots a little with your solution.

This program seems to do what you need. I have added some commas to your *"output format"* as your example has no placeholders for initial empty fields.

I have kept the hash characters for this purpose. Obviously it is trivial to change them for spaces, replacing `s/^(#*)//` with `s/^(\s*)//`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @row;

while (<DATA>) {

  chomp;
  s/^(#*)//;
  my $i = length($1) / 2;

  if ($i == 1 and m<(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})>) {
    $row[$i] = $1;
  }
  else {
    $row[$i] = $_;
  }

  if ($i == 2) {
    print join(',', @row), ";\n";
    @row = ('') x 3;
  }
}


__DATA__
Component1
##(111) Amar Sen <amar.sen@gmail.com> <No comment> 2013/04/01
####/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt
##(1199) Prashant Singh <psinsgh@gmail.com> <No comment> 2013/04/24
####/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24
####/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile25
####/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile26
##(1204) Anthony Li <anthon.li@gmail.com> <No comment> 2013/04/25
####/Com/src2
```

**output**

```
Component1,2013/04/01,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt;
,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24;
,,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile25;
,,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile26;
,2013/04/25,/Com/src2;
```

---

**Update**

It makes more sense to cascade values from columns one and two into subsequent rows where they are not supplied. If you remove the line `@row = ('') x 3` from my program it will do just that, with this output

```
Component1,2013/04/01,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile25;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile26;
Component1,2013/04/25,/Com/src2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It works the way I need except at one place where its failing. In fact my mistake, I should have sampled it more. If I have Component2 and Component3 (with no space at beginning), code should output Component2 and Component3 as well irrespective of whether it has data or not but the code only outputs those lines which has data.I have updated the textfile and output format in my question.Please have a look.